# How can I programmatically check if an app is running in TestFlight beta mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, testflight

Is there a way to programmatically determine if the installed version of an iOS came from TestFlight (beta) or production (App Store)? To simplify testing of in-app purchases, I'd like to disable the entire store flow for beta testers.

Bonus points for providing the answer in both Objective-C and Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    if ([[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"embedded"
                                        ofType:@"mobileprovision"]) {
      // not from app store, eg: testflight or others
    } else {
      // from app store

}
```

Refferece answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431994/detect-testflight)

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this would work? Where does the iTunesMetadata plist come from and why would it be there in one situation and not another?