# Is it possible to see if an in app purchase was made in sandbox mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, testing, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I am working on an iOS library that records a successful in app purchase to our API for later processing.  What I would like to be able to do is log to our api if the IAP was made in sandbox (with a test user) or not.

Answer (score 1):

That information is in the receipt.  You can:
1) grab the receipt and submit it to the Apple servers (sandbox or production).  It will come back either valid or with a 21007/21008 error revealing its environment.
2) grab the receipt and decode it.  There is an undocumented field that indicates whether or not it is from the sandbox.

I'd go with #1

Answer (score 0):

After a while of hunting I came across this post which seems to be what I am trying to do. [Check if iOS app is live in app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906504/check-if-ios-app-is-live-in-app-store) I will update the post once I am fully deployed and tested but it seems to be working for now.