# iOS 8 testflight beta push notification tokens

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I need to find out whether the deviceToken I receive from apple is a SANDBOX token or a PRODUCTION token.

Before using a distribution build configuration will result in PRODUCTION tokens, but with the testflight beta program, I actually receive device tokens that are SANDBOX tokens, even when I build with a production certificate for signing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Receipts are also sandboxed... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26081543/how-to-tell-at-runtime-whether-an-ios-app-is-running-through-a-testflight-beta-i/26113597#26113597

Answer (score 1):

To dispatch push notifications through TestFlight, you need the production receipt on the server side. The production receipt is created in the Apple Developer Center under the bundle/app id. The production certificate should be downloaded from the ADC site, converted from .p12 to .pem using openssl, and then referenced by the script that performs the push notifications.