# How can my app detect that it was distributed via the new TestFlight?

Tags: ios, testflight, beta

I'm going to use Apple's relaunched TestFlight service to distribute a beta, and I'd like to force a certain message to be visible when running as a beta.

Obviously there's a lot of ways to solve this, but it got me thinking; has Apple provided a way to detect if the currently running app was distributed via TestFlight? iOS clearly differentiates it to the user, so I thought there'd be a way for the developer to tell, as well. Alas, I haven't found anything in the Apple Developer site.

Comment: Why not treat all app distributed via TestFlight as BETA and display a message.  You could set a BETA flag in plist

Comment: "Obviously there's a lot of ways to solve this, but" this question is asking specifically about detecting TestFlight, not setting a flag on the developer side.

Comment: This is going to difficult since the Beta via Apple's TestFlight looks the same as the AppStore version. I don't think you can actually detect it.

Comment: Perhaps apps distributed through TestFlight won't have a receipt, whereas ones downloaded through the App Store would. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell at runtime whether an iOS app is running through a TestFlight Beta install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26081543/how-to-tell-at-runtime-whether-an-ios-app-is-running-through-a-testflight-beta-i)

Comment: Yes, and the accepted answer there validates Marcus Adams' comment above about using the receipt. Thanks!