# Detect if App is production version or Development version

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I need to detect at run time whether my apps copy is Production/Development version. Is there any methods to achieve the same.

I am looking forward to develop push notification API which will send APNS messages to server accordingly(i.e. sandbox or without sandbox).

Any help? thanx in advance.

Comment: you could use schemas, in my applications I have a development and a production schema and a plist file for each one, so you can run in either production or development mode locally

Comment: You can add a compilation parameter to each configuration and check that one (Preprocessor Macros, as an example).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26081543/how-to-tell-at-runtime-whether-an-ios-app-is-running-through-a-testflight-beta-i

Answer (score 19):

In that case you can use conditional compiling and check if you are in debug mode.

In your project settings you should have defined a preprocessor macro to indicate the debug build:

[image: preprocessor settings]

you can use that or define your own.

in your code you can put:

```
    NSString* platform = @"ios";
#if DEBUG
    platform = @"ios_sandbox";
#endif
```

everything between `#if DEBUG` and `#endif`  will only be compiled when `DEBUG=1` is defined (in this case only in debug configuration) so at the end you will have in `platform` variable the value of `ios` in release builds and `ios_sandbox` in debug builds.