# How to identify the app running environment including Test Flight

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I'm developing iOS app and need to identify the environment where the app is running to classify the API endpoint. I want to know the app is running under whether production, simulator and also Test Flight.
I've already done classifying production and simulator by User-defined setting, but am still not sure how I can identify Test Flight. 
Any tips? thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell at runtime whether an iOS app is running through a TestFlight Beta install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26081543/how-to-tell-at-runtime-whether-an-ios-app-is-running-through-a-testflight-beta-i)

Comment: For macOS https://gist.github.com/lukaskubanek/cbfcab29c0c93e0e9e0a16ab09586996

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking to get this information from within the app, you can get all this from `appStoreReceiptURL` of `NSBundle`

From [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSBundle/appStoreReceiptURL)...

> For an application purchased from the App Store, use this application bundle property to locate the receipt. This property makes no guarantee about whether there is a file at the URL—only that if a receipt is present, that is its location.

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL?.lastPathComponent
```

For implementation refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26081543/how-to-tell-at-runtime-whether-an-ios-app-is-running-through-a-testflight-beta-i) question

Comment: Thanks! @penkey-suresh 


    let receiptURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL!
    let receiptURLString = receiptURL.path!
    let isRunningTestFlightBeta = (receiptURLString.rangeOfString("sandboxReceipt") != nil)

worked!

Comment: Do consider accepting the answer if it solves your issue :)

Comment: Sorry about that. Just wanted to add comment to thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Also can use `environment` field from receipt fields. Please check the attached screenshot for `sandbox` and `production` receipts.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5.** Use the below WhereAmIRunning class to check the environment.

```
import Foundation

class WhereAmIRunning {

    // MARK: Public

    func isRunningInTestFlightEnvironment() -> Bool{
        if isSimulator() {
            return false
        } else {
            if isAppStoreReceiptSandbox() && !hasEmbeddedMobileProvision() {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
    }

    func isRunningInAppStoreEnvironment() -> Bool {
        if isSimulator(){
            return false
        } else {
            if isAppStoreReceiptSandbox() || hasEmbeddedMobileProvision() {
                return false
            } else {
                return true
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: Private

    private func hasEmbeddedMobileProvision() -> Bool{
      if let _ = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "embedded", ofType: "mobileprovision") {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    private func isAppStoreReceiptSandbox() -> Bool {
        if isSimulator() {
            return false
        } else {
          if let appStoreReceiptURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL,
            let appStoreReceiptLastComponent = appStoreReceiptURL.lastPathComponent as? String, appStoreReceiptLastComponent == "sandboxReceipt" {
                    return true
            }
            return false
        }
    }

    private func isSimulator() -> Bool {
        #if arch(i386) || arch(x86_64)
            return true
            #else
            return false
        #endif
    }
}
```