# Can testflight version contain debugging function while app store version not？

Tags: ios, xcode, build, macros, testflight

I have some libraries which I want link to release version but not testflight version. But the two versions seem to be the same. How can I distinguish them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell at runtime whether an iOS app is running through a TestFlight Beta install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26081543/how-to-tell-at-runtime-whether-an-ios-app-is-running-through-a-testflight-beta-i)