# Best way to write a env conditional in a react-native mobile app?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, testflight

We have tow environments, `Testing`, and `Production`

We use `Testing` in two different scenarios; on our local devices, and when we have our app deployed to TestFlight for our remote users to test.

We differentiate between our two domains manually within our `config.js` file :

```
const domain = 'testing-server.herokuapp.com'; // 'actualWebsite.com';
```

So once everything is all set to go, we change the site to `actualWebsite.com` and deploy. But! Is there anyway to make this ENV aware, so that it just knows it was on production and therefore would automagically point to `actualWebsite.com` and if it was on TestFlight or on our local, it would automagically use `testing-server.herokuapp.com` ?

Comment: Is your testing being set in NODE_ENV or how?

Answer (score 0):

```
const domain = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'testing-server.herokuapp.com' : 'actualWebsite.com';
```

Alternatively you can install [babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables) and declare `domain` as an environment variable, and set a different environment variable value in your build tool.

[react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config) is another choice.

Comment: `process.env.NODE_ENV` won't differentiate between TestFlight and Production

Comment: @trip What will then?

Comment: You can create a native module and bridge it to RN to check for TestFlight if you really need that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26081543/how-to-tell-at-runtime-whether-an-ios-app-is-running-through-a-testflight-beta-i

Comment: You can also set the `process.env` in your build command for TestFlight, but this means you have to re-build it for production (instead of just moving it from TestFlight to production), which is not a very good idea imo.