# How to know installed application is installed via TestFlight or AppStore?

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

I want to know about how to check user installed application is installed via `Testflight` or `AppStore`. So based on that I want to make some environmental change in whole application.

Is there anyway to find that by coding. Is Apple is providing any `API` for it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Testflight is for the beta testing.. how users can download your app from there ??

Comment: Some of my testers are testing from testflight and sometimes they are downloading application from AppStore to check live application. So I want to know whether they have downloaded application from Testflight or AppStore.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell at runtime whether an iOS app is running through a TestFlight Beta install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26081543/how-to-tell-at-runtime-whether-an-ios-app-is-running-through-a-testflight-beta-i)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found little snippet about how to know if application is installed via TestFlight.

Here, `appStoreReceiptURL` is an instance property, which we can find from main bundle.

[image]

```
func isTestFlight() -&gt; Bool {
    guard let appStoreReceiptURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL else {
    return false
    }
    return appStoreReceiptURL.lastPathComponent == "sandboxReceipt"
}
```

Comment: Thanks - still working for me as of iOS 14 and Xcode 12.4

Comment: Useful however - for those with ability to read deleted posts - it’s well worth reading @matt’s comments below.