# What's the path name of appStoreReceiptURL in App Review environment?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, testflight, receipt-validation

Is `Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL?.lastPathComponent` "receipt" or "sandboxReceipt" in App Review environment?

I want to know the result of [this TestFlight check code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26081543/how-to-tell-at-runtime-whether-an-ios-app-is-running-through-a-testflight-beta-i) in App Review environment.

Answer (score 0):

`Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL?.lastPathComponent` is "**receipt**" in App Review environment.