# Flutter - How to conditionally set a variable based on Environment (TestFlight / App Store)

Tags: ios, flutter

I am trying to build a Flutter app for iOS release with the following condition.

1. If the app is run on Testflight, the base API path should be set to https://api-qa.myapp.com/
2. But if it's run from App Store, it should instead be set to https://api.myapp.com/

The idea is that all Testflight releases would not affect my PROD environment and should instead connect to the QA environment.

Is there a way to do this with a single build?

Comment: It looks like it’s possible to do it on ios, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26081543/how-to-tell-at-runtime-whether-an-ios-app-is-running-through-a-testflight-beta-i. so it’s therefore possible to do it on Flutter. Unfortunately, I couldn’t find any packages addressing it.

Comment: There is some information here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels  to use swift or objective-C code in parallel with flutter.