# how to check user has updated app from app store / play store and after that clear the async storage ? React native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, asyncstorage

We have an app on app store and play store , but once user update the app its not working properly ,if user clear the cache and storage it working fine.

we want to check wether user has updated app from app store / play store based on some version number and after that clear the async storage

Comment: what exactly is not working after update?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to know that in react native till now, but on the other hand, you can check it using native java for android from [here](https://androiderrors.com/detect-if-an-app-is-installed-from-play-store/).

```
boolean verifyInstallerId(Context context) {
    // A list with valid installers package name
    List<String> validInstallers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("com.android.vending", "com.google.android.feedback"));

    // The package name of the app that has installed your app
    final String installer = context.getPackageManager().getInstallerPackageName(context.getPackageName());

    // true if your app has been downloaded from Play Store 
    return installer != null && validInstallers.contains(installer);
}
```

and here's a native solution for `IOS` using native from this old answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26081543/how-to-tell-at-runtime-whether-an-ios-app-is-running-through-a-testflight-beta-i).

I prefer you delete the storage for all users in your next update to solve the issue.

And if you can specify the error you have maybe we can help on it.

Answer (score 0):

In this new version, you can do something like

```
const savedVersion = await AsyncStorage.getItem('savedVersion'); // this will return null, because the previous version didn't set this value

const currentVersion = DeviceInfo.getVersion();

if (!savedVersion||semver.lt(savedVersion, currentVersion)) {
  await clearAllStorage();
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('savedVersion', currentVersion);
}
```