# Check at compile time if an iOS app is running through a TestFlight or AppStore or local install in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to know if is it possible to check at compile time if a build will be running using TestFlight, AppStore or a local build created by developer.

I just want to set a environment parameter based on this just like the example below.

```
#if localBuild
    let ambientePadrao:ambiente = ambiente.dev
#else TestFlight
    let ambientePadrao:ambiente = ambiente.stage
#elsif AppStore
    let ambientePadrao:ambiente = ambiente.prod
#endif
```

The post below shows how to do that, but it works at running time. I want to know if is it possible to do that at compile time

[How to tell at runtime whether an iOS app is running through a TestFlight Beta install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26081543/how-to-tell-at-runtime-whether-an-ios-app-is-running-through-a-testflight-beta-i)

Comment: Doesn't seem possible since at compile time you don't know whether the app will be run from Test Flight or submitted to the App Store. Also keep in mind that a build initially sent to Test Flight could then be submitted to the App Store without another build or any changes. At best, at compile time, you can differentiate between "Debug" and "Release" builds.